# 1:2 stepup transformer suitability

Tags: transformer, pulse

I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to transformers. I need a 1:2 stepup from approx 30V to 60V peak to peak at 120kHz. I am thinking of using the Murata [782485/35C](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1482182.pdf):

Which seems to be optimized for RS485 (at a guess). Opinions?

Comment: Current in secondary <50mA

Answer (score 1):

You should know that such a transformer will probably significantly distort your nice clean square waves, and won't provide the isolation you may want for RS485. It'd be a better idea to use second power source and an RS485 driver with optical isolation between your circuit and the driver. Then stray voltage spikes (lightening, inductive coupling, etc) may eat your driver but not the rest of your circuit.

RS485! **That** brings back twenty-year-old memories! I did a lot of RS422 and RS485 work back then...

Comment: In this case, the waveform is approximately sine, with some distortions.

Comment: In that case, it'll probably work pretty nicely.

Answer (score 0):

That particular transformer is designed for considerably higher frequencies (500kHz) and somewhat lower voltages (10Vp-p) than you are using- there's a fair possibility the core will saturate, as your situation represents more than an order of magnitude higher flux density in the core compared to the original design situation.

You have ~11V RMS on the primary, so in the **best case** (no saturation) the magnetizing current would be ~65mA RMS if I did the math right (based on the nominal primary inductance of 234uH).  If it saturates, the DC resistance is something like 1/4 ohm so "bad things" will likely happen.